# iOS 16 barcode not scanning properly

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I've a QR code & barcode scanning native iOS app which was working properly before iOS 16. After iOS 16 release, the bar code scanning happens only when positioning the bar code at the bottom part of the `rectOfInterest`.

Right now I've defined the `metadatObjectTypes` as below:

> captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr, .ean13, .ean8, .aztec, .upce, .code39, .code39Mod43, .code93, .upce, .interleaved2of5, .itf14, .code128, .pdf417]

But the bar code scanner is working properly (**it scans everywhere inside the rectOfInterest**) if we set scanner's *metadataObject* type **omitting QR code type** (.qr) as below but it results in **not scanning** the QR code.

Have referred the below two links where they are trying to scan either of the bar codes but not both types:

1. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714341
2. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715055

As I couldn't find the solution for this issue, someone kindly suggest the possible fix for scanning both QR and barcode types.

Answer (score 0):

try updating your iOS version on the device to at least 16.3

I read a post while looking for this problem with some of our users reporting similar issues. Apparently, it's due to a bug with iOS system update, which is not the fault of app devs.

Comment: This is still issue in iOS 16.4